# Inheriting Similar Models with Different DB Columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently trying to model a sports profile. Each player has a different profile for each sport they participate in that document the uniqueness of each sport. For example a player Bob. Bob has a BasketballProfile and a SoccerProfile. Alice can have a BaseballProfile and a SoccerProfile.

[image: Profiles]

batting_hand, pitching_hand, shooting_hand, dunk, are just a few example  attributes that I'd want to add.

I've looked into Single Table Inheritance and Polymorphic Association but they don't seem to be for models with additional attributes because of the number of nulls that will be in the database.

```
class Player< ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :Profiles
end

class Profile< ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :Player
end

class BasketballProfile < Profile
end

class BaseballProfile < Profile
end
```

**How would you model Models that are similar but that have additional database columns? Can you inherit similar models with additional DB columns?** BasketballProfile and BaseballProfile both have position but one has batting_hand while the other has dunk.

Should I make different stand alone models of BaseballProfile, SoccerProfile, BasketballProfile, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So STI alone won't help, unless you don't mind having empty fields in the DB rows for the classes that don't use those.

Other approach is to have Profile have all the common fields and have one polymorphic SportSpecificProfile (for the lack of a better name) and this can be a BasketballProfile, BaseballProfile, but they don't share tables or anything.

Comment: I was originally planning on having them in the same table. Would reverse polymorphic associations be what you are describing? https://gist.github.com/runemadsen/1242485

Comment: Yeah, I guess I only call it polymorphic associations. You can't have them on the same table, without having empty fields on the table. But having those is up to you, so you could do it that way, just know the drawbacks.